# tfdbg on slim not compatible with Object Detection API

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, tensorflow

## Description

I want to debug a NaN error with tfdbg on the Object Detection API rfcn network. I checkout latest version of 'tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py' to include the tfdbg support. After hitting 'run' twice in tfdbg, I encountered the following error. This can be reproduced with the pets example by adding 'session_wrapper=tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession' to the 'slim.learning.train' in 'models/object_detection/trainer.py'.

## System

GPU: Single 1080 Ti

Tensorflow: r1.3 with latest checkout of 'tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py' to include tfdgb support on slim.

## Logs

```
2017-09-03 13:04:11.473343: I tensorflow/core/debug/debug_graph_utils.cc:229] For debugging, tfdbg is changing the parallel_iterations attribute of the Enter/RefEnter node "gradients/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/Enter_1_grad/b_acc_1" on device "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0" from 16 to 1. (This does not affect subsequent non-debug runs.)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, Node name 'parallel_read/filenames/Assert/Assert/data_0' is not found in partition graphs of device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "object_detection/train.py", line 202, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in main
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/projects/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 310, in train
session_wrapper=tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 777, in train
sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in exit
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 964, in managed_session
self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
enqueue_callable()
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py", line 570, in wrapped_runner
callable_runner_args=runner_args)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py", line 532, in run
run_end_resp = self.on_run_end(run_end_req)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 319, in on_run_end
self._dump_root, partition_graphs=partition_graphs)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py", line 690, in init
self._load_all_device_dumps(partition_graphs, validate)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py", line 712, in _load_all_device_dumps
self._load_partition_graphs(partition_graphs, validate)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py", line 1009, in _load_partition_graphs
self._validate_dump_with_graphs(device_name)
File "/local/mnt/workspace/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py", line 1208, in _validate_dump_with_graphs
"device %s." % (datum.node_name, device_name))
ValueError: Node name 'parallel_read/filenames/Assert/Assert/data_0' is not found in partition graphs of device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0.
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be a Tensorflow bug. Can you please file a Github issue with a [minimal, self-contained, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: @PeterHawkins I did. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2328